# How can I build a Dockerfile in finch when sitting behind a proxy and using cntlm as local proxy?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Given the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nexus.company.net/python:3.10-slim-bullseye

ARG TWINE_USERNAME
ARG TWINE_PASSWORD
ARG COMMIT_SHA

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1
ENV APP_PATH=/home/appuser/app

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main" | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list \
    && apt-get update && apt -t bullseye-backports upgrade -y \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc procps build-essential

RUN set -ex && pip install -U pip && pip install pipenv

WORKDIR ${APP_PATH}
COPY . ./

RUN set -ex && echo "${TWINE_USERNAME}" && pipenv sync --system

RUN groupadd -g 999 appuser && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g appuser appuser
USER appuser

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/appuser/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When trying to build with:

```
finch build --build-arg TWINE_USERNAME=xxx --build-arg TWINE_PASSWORD="$TWINE_PASSWORD" \
--build-arg NO_PROXY='localhost,127.0.0.*,10.*,192.168.*' \
--build-arg http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 \
--build-arg https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 \
--build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128 \
--build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128 \
-t appname .
```

I keep getting network error:

```
...
#0 0.230 deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
#0 0.253 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
#0 0.253   Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:3128 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 0.253 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
#0 0.253   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3128:
#0 0.253 Err:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
#0 0.253   Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:3128 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 0.253 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
#0 0.253   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3128:
#0 0.257 Reading package lists...
#0 0.263 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:3128 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 0.263 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3128:
#0 0.263 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3128:
#0 0.263 W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:3128 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
#0 0.263 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
...
```

I assume my problem is the proxy configuration, but I am not sure what is expected.

I tried various proxy settings like but nothing seems to be working. `127.0.0.1:3128` is the proxy setting which is working with my general setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer: BuildKit needs to know the hosts real address during build. `localhost` is only pointing to the builder container and not to the build host.

To find the build host address:

```
export SYSID_HOST="http://$(ifconfig | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f2 -d: | head -n1):3128"
```

Then the final command for building is:

```
finch build --build-arg TWINE_USERNAME=xxx --build-arg TWINE_PASSWORD="$TWINE_PASSWORD" \
    --build-arg NO_PROXY='localhost,127.0.0.*,10.*' \
    --build-arg http_proxy=${SYSID_HOST} \
    --build-arg https_proxy=${SYSID_HOST} \
    --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=${SYSID_HOST} \
    --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=${SYSID_HOST} \
    -t appname .
```